# Syntax error PHP code

Tags: php, html

I have this code:

```
?php 
    if ( is_page('1708')) { 
        <div id="portofoliu"></div>
    } 
?>
```

And this my error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/dacproie/public_html/eventos/wp-content/themes/eventos/header.php on line 141

What is wrong in this code?

Can you help me to solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm no PHP expert but shouldn't that be `<?php ` ?

Comment: To embed html directly in your PHP script, you need to drop out of PHP with `?>` then switch back to PHP with `<?php` again afterwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing `echo`:

```
<?php 
    if ( is_page('1708')) { 
        echo '<div id="portofoliu"></div>';
    } 
?>
```

You can't mix HTML and PHP this way.

Another option is (for longer HTML code):

```
<?php 
    if ( is_page('1708')) { 
?>
        <div id="portofoliu"></div>
<?php    
    }
?>
```

OR

```
<?php 
    if ( is_page('1708')) :
?>
        <div id="portofoliu"></div>
<?php    
    endif;
?>
```

And, of course, PHP begins with `<?php` but it seems to be just copy&paste error.

Answer (score 0):

Might seem obvious but... You need to escape your html to be a string. Otherwise PHP trys to execute it.

```
<?php 
    if ( is_page('1708')) { 
        echo '<div id="portofoliu"></div>';
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close and open PHP tags:

```
<?php 
    if ( is_page('1708')) { 
?>
        <div id="portofoliu"></div>
<?php
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
<?php 
    if ( is_page('1708')) { 
        echo '<div id="portofoliu"></div>';
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Your code contains parse error too.

Comment: Yep, missed a semicolon. Been writing Python all week!